# ActiveX error when opening part of intranet website

Tags: web, activex, intranet

a intranet website which works perfectly on IE and windows 7

when it runs on windows 10 , it automatically goes to edge and get below errors

cannot load card print activeX

windows has blocked this software because it cant verify the publisher

name :....

publisher :unknown publisher

how to solve

checked all ativex settings on internet options , still same error
installed plugin , but still error not loading page with activex
if enable activex filtering on working computer which mentioned above , same error will come , so it is related activex